# Format negative to positive values with red to green gradient

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm transferring and Excel report to R Shiny and the last part I'm stuck on is conditional formatting. I want negative values to be shades of red and positive values to be shades of green. If the values are all negative, then I only want shades of red, only green for positive.

I get why the code below is producing the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3nmm.jpg), I just have no idea how to break up the values as Excel does.

```
brks <- quantile(df[,2:4], probs = seq(.05, .95, .05), na.rm = TRUE)
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c('red','white','green'))
clrs <- colfunc(length(brks) + 1)
datatable(df, rownames = TRUE, options=list(dom='t', pageLength=12, columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = 0)))) %>%
      formatStyle(names(df[,2:4]), backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks, clrs)) %>%
      formatPercentage(2:4,1) %>%
      formatStyle('TOTAL', fontWeight = 'bold') %>%
      formatStyle(0, target='row', fontWeight = styleEqual(dim(df)[1], 'bold'))
```

I tried using two brks and clrs and then two formatStyles, however that didn't work.

```
brks_red <- quantile(df[,2:4][df[,2:4]<0], probs = seq(.05, .95, .05), na.rm = TRUE)
brks_grn <- quantile(df[,2:4][df[,2:4]>0], probs = seq(.05, .95, .05), na.rm = TRUE)
datatable(df) %>%
     formatStyle(names(df[,2:4]), backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks_red, clrs_red)) %>%
     formatStyle(names(df[,2:4]), backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks_grn, clrs_grn))
```

I also want to keep it as DT since I have 3 other DTs showing on this tab. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way which guarantees that the value 0 is mapped to white.

```r
library(DT)

x <- round(c(rnorm(24), 0), 4) # we have to round to get equality in styleEqual()
m <- max(abs(x))
y <- (m + x) / (2 * m) # maps x to (0,1) such that 0 is mapped to 0.5

dat <- data.frame(x = x)
colfunc <- colorRamp(c('red', 'white', 'green'))
cols <- colfunc(y) # rgb codes, to be converted below
clrs <- rgb(cols[, 1], cols[, 2], cols[, 3], maxColorValue = 255)

datatable(dat, rownames = TRUE) %>%
  formatStyle("x", backgroundColor = styleEqual(dat$x, clrs))
```

---

## EDIT

Perhaps better, with the following way you're sure that the min is mapped to "full red", the max is mapped to "full green" and the 0 is mapped to white. Of course this requires that the min is negative. Instead of `c(min(x), 0, max(x))` you can supply a range like `c(-6, 0, 6)`.

```r
interpfun <- splinefun(
  c(min(x), 0, max(x)),
  c(0, 0.5, 1)
)
y <- interpfun(x)
```